# How to let a user choose different Facebook permissions in the same page?

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Suppose you want to build a webpage with Facebook PHP SDK, where you want to allow the user to select the information Facebook will return to the server. I've came with the following code to allow an user to either choose from allowing Facebook to send only the basic profile or else to also send the pages managed by this user.

```
session_start();

// Load the Facebook PHP SDK
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';

define('APP_ID', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');
define('APP_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$fbProfile = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'     => APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.7'
]);
$fbPages = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'     => APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.7'
]);

$helperProfile = $fbProfile->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$redirectUrlProfile = 'http://www.example.com/link1.php';
$loginUrlProfile = $helperProfile->getLoginUrl($redirectUrlProfile);
echo '<a href="' . $loginUrlProfile . '">Get profile with Facebook!</a><br>';

$helperPages = $fbPages->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['pages_show_list']; // Optional permissions

$redirectUrlPages = "http://www.example.com/link2.php";
$loginUrlPages = $helperPages->getLoginUrl($redirectUrlPages, $permissions);
echo '<a href="' . $loginUrlPages . '">Get pages with Facebook!</a>';
```

If I use the above code (commenting the non-relevant parts) with only **one** facebook object to either retrieve the profile or the pages managed by user (but not both), everything works fine. But if I use **both** objects concurrently to give a choice to the user, I get a `FacebookSDKException`. I guess this is due to CRSF cookies.

Is there any way to circunvent this problem?

Comment: why would you initialize the facebook php sdk twice? that does not make any sense...

Comment: @luschn: I must admit I'm a novice to Facebook Graph API and to Facebook PHP SDK. I used two new Facebook objects, because I thought I can only associate one redirect URL to each Facebook object. Since I have two redirect URLs, my thought was that two Facebook objects are needed. Anyway, following your remark, I removed one Facebook object, and with the other Facebook object I generated the first link, then the second link. The page still didn't work, and I got the same error I had before (the first link won't work).

Comment: next question: why use 2 different redirect urls? why not just check which permissions the user approved, in one redirect url? you are making it way too complicated.

Comment: @luschn: I use two diferent URLs because this is done in a page where a user can choose between two courses of action. One only needs the FB profile, while the other needs info about the FB pages of the user. I thought of your solution, but since [Facebook recommends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking) to only ask permissions which are really needed, if I have a general link which asks for the FB profile and pages of a user, I am asking more permissions than needed in the 1st case. But probably you're right - Perfect is the enemy of good

Comment: i am not sure why people user the php sdk for login anyway, it is so much easier with the javascript sdk. and you can easily just use the permissions you want without dealing with separate links and stuff. take a look at this: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/ - also, you don´t need to deal with redirect urls, which is much better for the user experience anyway.

Comment: @luschn: Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess this is due to CRSF cookies.

Correct. Calling the `getLoginUrl` method creates a new random `state` value and writes it into the session, overwriting any previously stored one.

So if you call the method twice (or more times), login will only work if you call the login dialog via the last login URL created, because only that contains a state value that matches the one stored in the session.

If you want to keep using two different redirect URIs, then you need to implement an additional step to create the correct login URL, and *only* that one.

So you have two links in your page, both pointing to a script on your server, and passing what permissions to ask for via a GET parameter (whether you want to pass permission names directly, or just a flag like `?loginmode=1`/`?loginmode=2`, is up to you.)

In that script, you decide which redirect URI and scope value to call the getLoginUrl method with - *once*. And then your script just redirects to that login URL.

(But keep in mind that the step that exchanges the code for an access token also requires the redirect URI parameter to be passed, again - and again with the *exact* same value that was used in the login dialog call.)

---

So doing it the way @luschn suggested in comments, using the JS SDK for login purposes, is probably much easier. `FB.login` can be called with different scopes from different points in your client-side JS code without any such problems.

Comment: The idea of the script is indeed a good one to circumvent the two links problem. In the end I used @luschn suggestion of using the JS SDK for login purposes (simpler and gives a better experience for the user).